# Is there a way to LEFT JOIN based on not null values? (BigQuery SQL)

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

Let's say I have Table1:

| First Name | Last Name | Zip Code | Profession | Favorite Sport |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Jessica | Alba | 11111 | Actress | null |
| Albert | Einstein | 00000 | Theoretical physicist | football |
| Nikola | Tesla | null | Inventor | football |
| Sabrina | null | 12345 | null | basketball |

Table2:

| First Name | Last Name | Zip Code | Favorite Food |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Jessica | Alba | null | Pasta |
| Albert | null | null | Burger and Fries |
| Albert | Einstein | 00000 | Sushi |
| Sabrina | null | 09876 | Sushi |

I want to LEFT JOIN Table1 and Table2 based on matches with "First Name", "Last Name" and "Zip Code". If one of these values are null, then I want the comparison to not depend on that column (for that particular data point).

Output I want:

| First Name | Last Name | Zip Code | Profession | Favorite Sport | Favorite Food |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Jessica | Alba | 11111 | Actress | null | Pasta |
| Albert | Einstein | 00000 | Theoretical physicist | football | Burger and Fries |
| Albert | Einstein | 00000 | Theoretical physicist | football | Sushi |
| Nikola | Tesla | null | Inventor | football | null |
| Sabrina | null | 12345 | null | basketball | null |

How can get this result?

Thank you!

Comment: Does it work if you try enclosing the join conditions with `IFNULL(t1.name=t2.name, true)`?

Answer (score 1):

Try below

```
select 
  coalesce(t1.first_name, t2.first_name ) first_name,
  coalesce(t1.last_name, t2.last_name ) last_name,
  coalesce(t1.zip_code, t2.zip_code ) zip_code,
  profession, favorite_sport, favorite_food
from table1 t1
left join table2 t2
on coalesce(t1.first_name = t2.first_name , true)
and coalesce(t1.last_name = t2.last_name, true)
and coalesce(t1.zip_code = t2.zip_code, true)          
and (coalesce(t1.first_name = t2.first_name , false)
or coalesce(t1.last_name = t2.last_name, false)
or coalesce(t1.zip_code = t2.zip_code, false))
```

if applied to sample data in your question - output is

[image]